# Ionic - ion-view header button net display

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I need to add button in the header section but unable to display button in the header section `ion-view`:

Here is my code :

```
<ion-view >
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
        <button class="button button-icon" >
            <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
        </button>
        <h1 class="title">ToDo</h1>
        <!-- New Task button-->
        <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="newTask()">
            <i class="icon ion-compose"></i>
        </button>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right"
                      ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap"
                      href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}">
                <img ng-src="{{chat.face}}">
                <h2>{{chat.name}}</h2>
                <p>{{chat.lastText}}</p>
                <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

                <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(chat)">
                    Delete
                </ion-option-button>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xatUE.png) is the output  image.

**Update**

I want to like this image `header bar` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG67S.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try use with `ion-nav-buttons` :

```
<ion-view title="ToDo">
   <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
  <button class="button" ng-click="newTask()">
    NEW
  </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right"
                      ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap"
                      href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}">
                <img ng-src="{{chat.face}}">
                <h2>{{chat.name}}</h2>
                <p>{{chat.lastText}}</p>
                <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

                <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(chat)">
                    Delete
                </ion-option-button>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Output in your header** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css classes:

```
<div class="bar bar-header">
  <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  <div class="h1 title">Header Buttons</div>
  <button class="button button-clear button-positive">Edit</button>
</div>
```

This will show in the header two icons on the corners and a text between them.

This is another example:

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">Right Button</button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content class="has-header">
  Some content!
</ion-content>
```

Hope it helps you

EDIT:

I saw that you are using a tabs app so i found this solution [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-how-to-get-header-bar-buttons-in-tab-application/7437):

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
  <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">
    I'm a button on the primary of the navbar!
  </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set 'has-subheader' class like this

```
<ion-content class='has-header has-subheader'>
...
</ion-content>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-view view-title="BBS">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader">
        <div class="button-bar">
            <a class="button">web game</a>
            <a class="button">mobile game</a>
        </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="has-header">

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

See:http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#subheader

Comment: your code is working without ion-view. [link](http://play.ionic.io/app/57fc749b6c65). update your view & i'll check it out